# Grant permissions "per user" in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to segregate access in DynamoDB per user. Basically the user should be able to create, query and delete tables (full read/write), but only tables created by him.

In a traditional database this would mean granting all rights for database X to user A, and all rights to database Y to user B.

How can I setup this in DynamoDB with IAM rights?

Comment: I have past experience of restricting such access by forcing users to have certain prefixes to their tables. Something like`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "allowallaccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:123456789012:table/user_*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: would that work for creating tables as well? they would only be able to create tables that starts with the prefix?

Comment: Yes it will allow dynamodb:* operations. Which includes create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can segregate the database tables to an user by setting an IAM policy like

```html
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "allowallaccess",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "dynamodb:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:123456789012:table/user_*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```